# protractor: follow up to another thread regarding how to handle locators that return array in page object model

Tags: javascript, protractor, pageobjects

I have a follow up question on this thread here: [What's the correct Protractor's syntax for Page Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739043/whats-the-correct-protractors-syntax-for-page-objects?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

This post was useful in understanding page objects especially the answer by : "Xotabu4" but I am running into slightly different problem.

Could someone please help me understand how would one handle a page object that returns an array of elements in a similar model as quoted in the above link by the user. For example, element.all($$) returns an array and I have to compare each element in the array with a certain text. How do I structure that in the model mentioned in the above hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is a dropdown list to choose destination implement by `<select>`, we need to verify all options with correct text.

```
<select class="destination">
  <option></option>
  ....
</select>

this.select_destination = element(by.css('select.destination'));

readDestinationOptionsText() {
  return this.select_destination.all(by.css('option')).getText();
}

verifyDestinationOptionsText(expectTexts) {
  return readDestinationOptionsText().then(function(actualTexts){
     return expect(actualTexts.join(',')).toEqual(expectTexts.join(','));
  });
}
```

Comment: readDestinationOptionsText() --> I assume this function would be in page object file and will return an array since it is using ".all", correct ?                                                                                                       
 The other function: verifyDestinationOptionsText(expectTexts) how will this function iterate and validate each element in the array as I see no looping done in this function. Probably javascript has different way of validating each value in the array. Could you please clarify